# Combine multiple timestamps to months in array - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I'm collecting timestamps for each site call analysis. Every call is a new entry in the MySQL table. To display the data in a JavaScript chart I want to sort the timestamps to months and count the calls per month.

The resulting PHP array should be like this

```
$calls = [
   "Jan" => [ 
       "calls" => 123
   ],
   "Mar" => [...]
]
```

How can I sort the timestamps by month an count the calls in each month?

```
$db->bind("pid",$user['PID']);

$calls = $db->query("SELECT MONTH(aufruf_time), count(*) 
FROM profile_analytics WHERE PID = :pid
GROUP BY MONTH(aufruf_time) 
ORDER BY aufruf_time");
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? How to obtain this data in a query? Or do you already have a query, but you need to restructure the result? Either way, when writing a question, you should present a clear problem you're facing. Right now, you only gave a specification of the expected result without any context.

Comment: I already collected the query from database. I'm struggling with processing the data to the above mentioned format.

Comment: 1. Question: How to sort the timestamps into months?
2. Question: How to count the calls per month?

Comment: If possible, you should sort the data by MySQL and not within you PHP code base, which is much more performant in most cases. Then iterate over the result set and build up your array (this is the easy part).

Comment: If you provide information about your database structure in a [minimal, reproducible example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query), maybe we can correctly help you do this at the query level. If you want to do it in PHP, then pleae share a sample of the array you have and the code you tried to group the data. Important details are missing from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this SQL would work:

```
SELECT MONTH(your_timestamp_column), count(*) 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY MONTH(your_timestamp_column) 
ORDER BY your_timestamp_column
```

It grouped the count of calls by month (ignoring the year here). Then you have to build your array with PHP. See the [MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) for further information

Comment: Wrong query. Will produce an error " Unknown column 'callDate' ".

Comment: It is only an example. I have no knowledge about the original database scheme. You have to adopt it. `callDate` is a column of type `timestamp`.

Comment: To be more precise, i have changed the column name into `your_timestamp_column`

Comment: This is what I get `Array ( [0] => Array ( [MONTH(aufruf_time)] => [count(*)] => 3 ) )`
How can I identify the month? Like April

Comment: Please add your PHP code snippet of querying and result iteration to show me what you do.

Comment: `your_timestamp_column` (and another columns of source table) is not available for sorting after grouping - output expressions only can be used..